# how do i get the index of a dynamically made clicked button

Tags: c#, forms

so i have a problem. in this scenario I have 12 buttons total, 0-11. I want to be able to click on the 5th (position 4 in the list it was created in) and have it recognise that it is in position 4 in the list it was created in.

```
List<Button> test = new List<Button> { };

        private void Details_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) //this for loop runs 12 times
            {

                Button var = new Button(); //makes a button "var"
                var.Text = ("test2.0"); //makes the text on the button 
                var.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.neat); //when you click on the button it runs the "neat function"
                test.Add(var); //adds it to the list called "test"


            }
            testing();
        }
        void neat(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("test"); //a message box
        }
        private void testing()
        {
            int topValue = 50; //this is just used to give each button a position on the panel on the form
            int leftvalue = 60;
            int count = 0;
            foreach (Button i in test) //this is pretty much just displaying the on the screen
            {


                i.Left = leftvalue;
                i.Top = topValue;
                panel1.Controls.Add(i); //adds the buttons to the pannel
                count += 1;
                leftvalue += 200;
                if (count % 3 == 0)
                {
                    topValue += 200;
                    leftvalue = 60; //every 4th button makes a new row
                }
            }
        }
```

so yeah. i just want to know how to know that when i click on the button in position 4 that it is in postition 4. the only way i could think of going about it would would ether give only false positives or wouldnt work all togeather.

and yes I will change it to padding eventually, don't lynch me

Comment: You can either store the button(s) in a collection, like an array or list, so that you have their reference for later, or you can use the Tag property.

Comment: I believe a `Button` has a `Tag` property. You could use that.

Comment: Or use a lambda `var.Click += (s, e) => this.neat(i);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach that's easy, clean and reliable is to use the built-in System.Linq class. Call the IndexOf() method on your list and pass in the button that was clicked. So, if your list is named 'test' then get the button's index like this:

```
test.IndexOf(button);
```

Consider combining this with making your own custom button by inheriting Button and baking this into your inherited class which might look like so:

```
    class MyIndexedButton : Button
    {
        readonly List<Button>_list;
        public MyIndexedButton(List<Button> list)
        {
            // This button adds itself to the list.
            list.Add(this);
            _list = list;   // Here we keep track of the list it's in.
        }
        protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        {
            // Here the button handles its own click event. 
            // Note: You DON'T need to do a += to subscribe!
            base.OnClick(e);
            // Now, to show that it works, we'll have it look 
            // in the list and retrieve its own index using
            // a System class called Linq.
            MessageBox.Show(
                "Clicked " + 
                _list.IndexOf(this) // Using System.Linq to detect the index.
                .ToString());
        }
    }
```

One nice thing is that even when buttons are removed or added, they will still dynamically know their correct index in your list. And here's a simple test driver. If you'd like to try it out you can copy the code or [download](https://github.com/IVSoftware/custom-button-with-index.git) the working example from GitHub.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    // We'll just make a little layout panel to manage the button positions.
    TableLayoutPanel _layout;   
    // Here's the list of Buttons you already had. We still need it.
    List<Button> _test = new List<Button> { };
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        _layout = new TableLayoutPanel() { ColumnCount = 4, RowCount = 4, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        Controls.Add(_layout);
        int row, column;
        for (int count = 0; count < 12; count++)
        {
            row = count / 4; column = count % 4;
            // When you make your custom button, just 
            // make sure you pass in the list like so:
            _layout.Controls.Add(new MyIndexedButton(_test), column, row);
        } 
    }
```

Now just run it and see if it works for you. When you click it should pop up a message saying the button ID is between 0 and 11 (the actual zero-based index).